# Is there a way to reference if cells have decimal point in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have create some code in VBA that will look through the cells in a worksheet in column B. If the code finds a cell value with a decimal (opposed to a whole number e.g. not 1, but 1.1) then print the cell value to right off it in another sheet.

I know it will be a loop and it will use offset hit etc. I havent tried this code in VBA i have just typed it as an example of what i will do in the question.

```
For each cell in Sheets("Sub Tasks").Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
     If cell = '(DECIMAL FORUMLA) Then
```

Comment: as for the decimal check, you could use `if cell.Value2 = CInt(cell.Value2) Then`, which would return `True` if cell.Value is an integer

Comment: Sorry just changed now, Lastrow is a variable to find the last filled row in column B fyi

Comment: @LawrenceForster On another note, please don't make edits that change the question because that invalidates the existing answers. I've rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("Sub Tasks").Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        If Val(cell.Value) <> Int(cell.Value) Then
            ' The number contains decimals.
            Dim valueToTheRight As Variant
            valueToTheRight = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            ' TODO: Add `valueToTheRight` into the appropriate place of the other sheet.
        End If
    Else
        ' The cell value is not a number.
        ' TODO: either do something about it or remove the `else` branch to ignore it.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, i have used some of your logic/code. I have changed my question has it isngt working correctly and i cannot spot the error.

Comment: @LawrenceForster In your new code, you never increment `n`.

Comment: ahhh so if i put a counter of n = n +1 will this work

Comment: @LawrenceForster Yes, that's right. Alternatively, you could convert the `For Each` loop to a `For` loop which will provide you with the incrementing variable.

Comment: Hi @AhmedAbdelhameed, I have a slight problem. when the code runs, it prints the values with a decimal perfectly. However, it doesnt print them in rows 2,3,4,5,6, and so on. It prints them with the same spacing as they are found in the Sub tasks sheets. Any ideas?

Comment: any help would be great

Comment: @LawrenceForster I can't tell you what goes wrong without seeing your code. That, however, seems like a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could evaluate the cells content?

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim cell

    For each cell in Sheets("Sub Tasks").Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
        If IsNumeric(c.Value2) And InStr(c.Value2, Application.DecimalSeparator) Then
            Debug.Print c.Value2
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

`IsNumeric` will test if the cell holds a number. i.e. skipping any strings with full stops in. and `Instr(c.value2, Application.DecimalSeparator)` will test for the decimal

Comment: It's worth noting that this will match a cell whose value is something like `1.0` (which might or might not be the behavior that the OP expects).

Comment: @GSerg it doesn't in my test

Comment: Yup, because you're implicitly doing `CStr(Value2)`. @AhmedAbdelhameed That was my thought too, it was wrong.

Comment: @GSerg You're right. However, it will still match `1.0` if the number format of the cell is set to Text. That's an edge case which the OP is unlikely to need to cover.